# jQuery JSON prepend / append unclosed tag rather than full tag only once for set of elements

Tags: jquery, json

jQuery - is it possible to dynamically wrap a bunch of generated `<li>` elements (fetched via JSON) appended to a div id with `<ol>`, for example?

I know of the `wrap()` function, but that seems to do it for each element of the li. Applying the `prepend("<ol>")` automatically closes the tag before the `each / append()` loop goes through

Comment: is there a method without having to populate a buffer variable first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) you can use [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) here, like this:

```
myLICollection.wrapAll('<ol></ol>');
```

Since you seem to already have the collection (as best as I can tell from the question) this should be a simple change.  [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) wraps *each* element in the set, where as [`.wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) wraps the entire set at once.

Comment: the problem with `.wrapAll()` is that it doesn't wrap the things contained within the classes... so if you have `<li class="wrapme"><img class="someOtherClassName"></li>` it'd just wrap the li's and not the img's..

Comment: nvm! was json async error causing the oddness. wrapAll works :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = "<ol>";
$.each(json, function(i, item) {
  string += "<li>" + item + "</li>";
});
string += "</ol>";
$("#myDiv").html(string);
```

No?

Comment: you have to store the values in memory this way - what if your json return is rather large.. just append to render on page directly